# OGR Layer Intersection

Tags: python, ogr, intersection

I am using what I would describe as the most primitive method of doing intersection with OGR. The short script below describes how I do it. Is there a best way of doing this?

```py
   from osgeo import ogr, osr
   shp1 = ogr.Open(file1)
   shp2 = ogr.Open(file2)

   SpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
   SpatialRef.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')
   # Create dst file here 
   dstshp = ogr.CreateDataSource('SomeFilename.shp')
   dstlayer = dstshp.CreateLayer()
   # define its attribute fields for dstlayer and create them

   layer1 = shp1.GetLayer(0)
   layer2 = shp2.GetLayer(0)

   for feature1 in layer1:
      geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
      attribute1 = feature1.GetField('FieldName1')
      for feature2 in layer2:
         geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()
         attribute2 = feature2.GetField('FieldName2')  
         intersection = geom2.intersection(geom1)
         dstfeature = ogr.Feature(dstlayer.GetLayerDefn())
         dstfeature.SetGeometry(intersection)
         dstfeature.setField(attribute1)
         dstfeature.setField(attribute2)
         dstfeature.Destroy() # and other features must be destroyed too
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some errors in your script but it is not the most important problem:

You cannot create a valid shapefile without specifying the geometry of the layer:

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dstshp = driver.CreateDataSource('SomeFilename.shp')
dstlayer = dstshp.CreateLayer('mylayer',geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
```

And you don't know *a priori* (upfront) the geometry of the resulting intersection layer. The intersection of two polygon layers is different from the intersection of a polygon layer and a polyline layer for example.

For that, you can get the geometry of the intersection by:

For example (with two polygons shapefiles):

```
layer1.GetGeomType()
3 # -> polygon
# create an empty geometry of the same type
union1=ogr.Geometry(3)
# union all the geometrical features of layer 1
for feat in layer1:
    geom =feat.GetGeometryRef()
    union1 = union1.Union(geom)
# same for layer2
union2=ogr.Geometry(layer2.GetGeomType())
for feat in layer2:
    geom =feat.GetGeometryRef()  
    union2 = union2.Union(geom)
# intersection
intersection = union1.Intersection(union2)
print intersection.GetGeometryName()
'MultiPolygon'
```

At this stage, you can save the resulting geometry to a shapefile (without the fields of the original layers):

```
dstshp = driver.CreateDataSource('SomeotherFilename.shp')
dstlayer = dstshp.CreateLayer('mylayer',geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
```

But if you want to use your script (a MultiPolygon is a collection of Polygons):

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dstshp = driver.CreateDataSource('SomeFilename.shp')
dstlayer = dstshp.CreateLayer('mylayer',geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
for feature1 in layer1:
   geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
   attribute1 = feature1.GetField('FieldName1')
    for feature2 in layer2:
       geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()
       attribute2 = feature2.GetField('FieldName2') 
       # select only the intersections
       if geom2.Intersects(geom1): 
          intersection = geom2.Intersection(geom1)
          dstfeature = ogr.Feature(dstlayer.GetLayerDefn())
          dstfeature.SetGeometry(intersection)
          dstfeature.setField(attribute1)
          dstfeature.setField(attribute2)
          dstfeature.Destroy()
```

Don't forget to define the fields before (look at [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook:Vector Layers](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-new-shapefile-and-add-data)). And it is much easier with the module [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and for assistance in improving the script. Much appreciated and it works. I will go through the entire OGR Cookbook. I found it to be helpful.

Comment: I have edited my own with your suggestions. The inclusion of 'if geom2.Intersects(geom1):' before doing the actual instersection has reduced the computational time by a big margin (more than half).

Comment: I don't follow the purpose of doing a Union first. What do you gain?

Comment: I'm not sure how the union works in the for loop, I keep getting a NoneType error. Having created `union1=ogr.Geometry(3)`, the line `union1 = union1.Union(geom)` keeps resulting in an  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Union'

Comment: I suppose you missed an important line (before dstfeature.destroy) from the answer, which can cause some headache whom implement this: ```dstlayer.CreateFeature(dstfeature)```

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd add my experience here. I've been working with situations where I might need to merge hundreds or thousands of polygons and the `Union` solution didn't quite cut it - the time to get the intersection of 1 polygon in 1 layer against a couple of hundred polygons in 1 other layer took ~15 secs. I managed to cut it down to 0.08ms by adding each polygon to a `MultiPolygon` and avoiding doing a `Union` for every polygon and `Simplify`ing the entire geometry at the end of the loop:

```
    union = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
    for feat in 
        union.AddGeometry(feat.GetGeometryRef())
    union1.Simplify(0)
```

Actually, I found for my purposes I didn't even need the `Simplify` - the intersection geometry seemed to behave as I needed it to without the extra function call.